# Unix - combine all rows into a comma-separated single row

Tags: linux, unix

I have following values in a file in separate lines:
California
New York
Washington
South Carolina
Kansas

What would be unix script to display them in a single line (as showb below)
'California', 'New York', 'Washington', 'South Carolina', 'Kansas'
[I do not want to have any intermediate file to achieve this.. just an echo code is fine]

Answer (score 6):

Use this command `tr '\n' ',' < input_file`

For single quotes use
`sed -e "s/^/'/" input_file | sed -e "s/$/'/" | tr '\n' ','`

(Not tested for single/double quote escaping issues)

For variable
`NEW_VAR=$(echo $VAR | sed -e "s/^/'/" | sed -e "s/$/'/" | tr '\n' ',')`

Comment: Thanks Sameer. Just to elaborate a little more... I am getting all the values from a database into a variable (say v_val) in my script. What would be unix command to combine rows from this variable into a new variable (say v_com) where values be in a comma separated single-quote format.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use awk to format the output. Does `sed and awk` ring a bell?

```
The file <test.txt>
California
New York
Washington
South Carolina
Kansas
```

$ `grep input file | awk '{print}' ORS=', '`

```
California, New York, Washington, South Carolina, Kansas
```

Then concatenate your string and look out for the proper output.

with awk you can try this

```
sudo awk -F'\n' '{if(NR == 1) {printf "\x27" $0 "\x27"} else {print "," "\x27" $0 "\x27"}}' test.txt

'California','New York','Washington','South Carolina','Kansas'
```

You can also try this

```
sudo awk 'BEGIN {RS=""}{gsub(/\n/,"\x27,\x27",$0); print $0}' test.txt
```

Comment: Why are you using `grep`?

Comment: @hek2mgl if you know what you're doing, you can use sed. for example, sed -n '/regex/p' /path/to/file then you pipe the second command.

Comment: While it makes no sense to replace grep for sed in that case, no search operation was required in the question. But it was required to enclose the state names in single quotes. Looks like you missed the question.

Comment: @hek2mgl I agree, grep an overkill for this simple operation